# How to Loop in threaded script on Python

Tags: python

Right now I have code in my script

```
def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self.one()
                self.two()
                self.three()
                self.four()
            except (IndexError, ProxyError, SSLError, ConnectionError, errno.ECONNREFUSED):
                print statusTime(self.index) + 'Bad Proxy'
                break

def jobWorker(username,password,proxy):
    bot = Bot(username,password,proxy)
    bot.start()
    bot.join()
    return
```

How can I tell python to continuously run def `run(self)` so basically keep looping through `self.one()`, `self.two()`, `self.three()`, `self.four()` so it doesnt stop. Right now each Bot stops at `self.four()` and doesnt start again at `self.one()`

Comment: And there is no exception thrown?

Comment: no without exception, i just want it to keep running

Answer (score 1):

you can put the function with in

```
def __init__(self):  
    self.run()
```

Comment: Ive put that at the end of my script however it still finishes after self.four()

Comment: you should put it with the same class of the method run(self)